# Starting developing an app with redux?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-framework

How to start developing an app with redux? 
I am new to Redux & have understood the principles, but need practical help to start with redux. How to set environment?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend watching all of the introductory videos on [egghead](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux) by redux's creator [@dan_abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov)
This will give you very good idea about all the things in redux.
For further understanding you can go through very extensive [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/) which covers all the concepts in redux beautifully.